# Adding n numbers in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm learning C, and am currently working my way up through command-line programs. I'm interested in writing a program which would add *n* terms to eachother, much like would a normal calculator. The number *n* would be defined by the number of terms the user enters (as opposed to a user-specified *n* inputted explicitly by the user before the operation). How can this be done? Should I use a `while` loop for this?

So far, I've tried simply defining a finite number of terms a user can enter (up to 10 terms, if it's fewer, simply replace the remaining terms with zeros).

```
scanf("%f%c%f%cf%cf%cf%cf%cf%cf%cf%cf", &num1, &op, &num2, &op, &num3, &op, &num4, &op, &num5, &op, &num6, &op, &num7, &op, &num8, &op, &num9, &op, &num10);

    // addition
    if (strcmp(&menuchoice, "a") == 0)
        {
            num3 = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10;
            return num3;
        }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: A `while` loop is one option; a `for` loop is also completely viable if you're processing the arguments to the program (you know how many arguments there are, or there's a sentinel value — a null pointer — at the end of the list).

Comment: You will need to capture how many terms were entered successfully, which is the return value from `scanf()`.  However, `scanf()` will wait until it can't get any more data, or it gets an invalid data item.  So, you're gonna need to do some work like read the line with `fgets()` and scan the line with `sscanf()`.  You'll probably want some blanks in the format string to handle optional spaces between numbers and operators.  If you're capturing the operators, you don't need the menu choice 'a' (though you'd need to provide `op1`, `op2`, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the sum only after *n* numbers have been entered, you'll have to have a way to find out that all the numbers have been input. One way to do this is to have a *sentinel* value that the user could enter. This could be a blank line or a string like `=`. If you are only adding positive numbers, you could use a negative number of `0` to indicate that the numbers have all been entered.

```
while (1)
{
    /* get input */
    if (/* should exit */)
        break;
    sum += input;
}
/* show sum */
```

If you are trying to emulate a calculator, you can simply show the running total after every number has been entered. That way you don't have figure out how big *n* is.

```
while (1)
{
    /* get input */
    sum += input;
    /* show sum */
}
```

Comment: In your second example, how would the input be read? Would it be something like, `scanf("%f%c", &input)`?

Comment: If you're going to use `"%f%c"`, you will need to pass something for the `%c` to go into.